# Types not aligning in mapped array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Take the following simplified code example (I've simplified it down from my real use case to get to the root of the problem):

```typescript
type TStringWrapper<C extends string> = { wrappedString: C };

type TWrapIfArrayOfStrings<S> = S extends Array<string>
    ? {
        [K in keyof S]: TStringWrapper<S[K]>
    }
    : never;
```

I get the following compiler error:

```js
Type 'S[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'S[keyof S]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'S[string] | S[number] | S[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'S[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

As far as I can see, this should compile because `S[K]` is guaranteed to be a string because of the conditional preceding it. How can this be rewritten so that it works?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're going to use this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
type TStringWrapper<C extends string> = { wrappedString: C };

type TWrapIfArrayOfStrings<S> = S extends Array<string>
    ? {
        [K in keyof S & number]: TStringWrapper<S[K]>
    }
    : never;
```

You know `S` extends `Array<string>` then a key of `S` is `number` not `string` like `S[0], S[1] ...` and so on.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgysATgSwHYHMDqiCGZKIA8AwlBAB7ASoAmAzlHUmugHxQC8UA3lAO658EGghQYAXFFIBfANwAoeaEixseAJIAzAIKJcIAPKbRLOoTjsucMpWr0ou-YSZi28qB6gB%20Hu8-%20AbQBpKDQoAGsIEAB7TShrADIoVABXAFsAIwhEAF1JeGYMNSEiOGCc1j8PaSqoSVQIADdshSA) is working example.